# How to get the join table name in an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am needing to find the name of a join table between two classes, for example, Client and Language. I need to be able to do this programmatically, because I am generating a complex SQL query that must automatically account for new relationships.

My best idea is to use table_name on both classes and combine them by the join table name convention:

```
if Client.table_name < Language.table_name
  Client.table_name + '_' + Language.table_name
else
  Language.table_name + '_' + Client.table_name
end
```

However, this does not account for a custom join table name. Is there a way to get the actual join table name?

Comment: Your code is slightly problematic, as the join table name comes from the class names, not from the table names.  You could have a class Client that has `self.table_name = 'users'` so getting the table name you'd be building `languages_users` when in fact the default join table is `clients_languages` .  Better would be `Client.to_s.tableize`

Comment: Also note that Rails 4 changed the naming convention for join tables with multiple words and with common starting words... ContractType and ContractPlan join table would be `contract_plans_types` http://ruby-journal.com/rails-4-changes-join-table-naming-convention/

Comment: @SteveTurczyn That is precisely the reason I wanted to find if there is an existing method that provides the generated or custom join table name without needing to know which is which. Fortunately, your answer below helped me find just such a method.

Answer (score 4):

Using Rails 5, the answer from SteveTurczyn wasn't working for me, but I found an alternative that does

```
Client.reflections["languages"].join_table
```

I know it's a few years after the question was asked, but hopefully this helps out somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a custom join table you can retrieve it as follows...

```
Client.new.association(:languages).options[:join_table]
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer led me to find a join_table method (go figure) in the ActiveRecord reflection class that gives the correct name, whether default or custom!

Comment: that's cool. You should post an answer to yourself to make this question more useful. I'd view it up.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears there is, indeed, a method that returns the precise name of the join table created by an ActiveRecord migration. Logically, there had to be one that provides the name at the time of generating the table, no?
So, the AssociationReflection class for ActiveRecord does indeed have a "join_table" method that returns the declared table name, if it exists, else the derived name.

There's some very interesting looking methods in that class definition. It's well worth a look.